# What does the following set mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How are the symbols $\cup$ and $\cap$ are used like that? Can someone please explain what the following does?

$$
\bigcup \left\{\{1\}, \{1,2\}, \bigcap\{\{2,3\}, \{3,4\}\}\right\}
$$

Comment: They are just the set union and intersection of the sets inside brackets.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff♦ what the above set is then?

Comment: You have a mismatched number of brackets.  You have six occurrences of $\{$ and only five occurrences of $\}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Yes, I forgot to add a } at the end

Comment: I added the brace at the end and made it bigger so that it's more obvious how the terms are grouped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When applied to collections of sets, they are the union of elements, and intersection of elements, of the collection.

$$\bigcup\{A, B, C\} = A\cup B\cup C
\\ \bigcap\{A, B, C\} = A\cap B\cap C
\\ \bigcup\{A, B, \bigcap\{C, D\}\} = A\cup B\cup(C\cap D)$$

And so forth.

Answer (score 4):

Given a set nonempty set $x$

$$
\bigcup x = \{z \mid \exists y \in x \colon z \in y \}
$$

and

$$
\bigcap x = \{ z \mid \forall y \in x \colon z \in y \}.
$$

Now let us consider $\bigcap \{ \{2,3\}, \{3,4\} \}$. We have $\{2,3\} \in \{ \{2,3\}, \{3,4\} \}$ and $\{3,4\} \in \{ \{2,3\}, \{3,4\} \}$. $z = 3$ is the only element that is in both $\{2,3\}$ and $\{3,4\}$. This yields $\bigcap \{ \{2,3\}, \{3,4\} \} = \{3\}$. I'm pretty confident that you can take it from here.